# Is it possible to prevent a site's text displaying in the Dev. Tools?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to prevent a site's text displaying in the Dev. Tools?

This is a copyright issue for a site displaying an Author's work.

The question: Are there alternative methods of delivering a stream of text that is not easily copied through Dev. Tools? Or is it a simple case of put up and lump it! Might the dedicated use of PHP pages prevent such a thing?

I am aiming to hamper casual but savvy users from copying text from the Dev. Tools, as opposed to tech. geniuses, which let's face it, if they want data they will get it!

To pre-answer questions about the site and how it works I include details below - but for this purpose I suspect it can be ignored.

---

Site Outline:

This is how the site works at present. The page (it's a one page htm site dedicated to allow a user to read a selected story). Everything other than the menu is loaded dynamically. I am not using a database to store the articles partly because some are long, plus it will be harder for the site owner to update it, maybe several times a day. I use .txt docs which are easily uploaded - the sites code handles the rest.

On a user's click I use a mix of JQuery, along with Ajax calls to PHP to search and retrieve and convert a selected article from a hex coded .txt file (using PHP's  hex2bin) stored in dedicated folders back into standard MarkDown text which they are written in, and then via a PHP Markdown parser where the content is converted into html. The result is then returned back to Ajax and displayed on the page. I do not use php pages, I only utilise the functions.

As for the .txt articles they named to include a '#' symbol which can prevent a 'casual user' from following an anchor link and displaying the content. Directory browsing is off and cursor selection on the displayed article is disabled. Finally, dynamic load prevents display in the 'page source' option. So, basic copyright protection is handled through standard methods. It is the Dev Tools which kills it!

---

I know I cannot prevent copying via Dev. Tools if the text is there, but I would love to know if it is possible to make whatever a user copies less useful somehow. I thought briefly about creating images on the fly but I do not like that idea, it's 'ugly' and some articles are long!

Are there alternative methods of displaying data, or have I missed the obvious? For instance, would a dedicated php delivered site prevent the end text showing up in the Dev. Tools? I do not believe that would be so, but... I am open to suggestions...

Comment: No. What dev tools see is what the browser sees, and if you want to hide something from _that_, then the only option is to not send it at all.

Comment: The big question is: why all of this? What is the real intention? If you want to hide from humans, put it behind a login... but you can't cheat on the machine eventually.

Comment: You could use an image

Comment: It's worth weighing the cost vs. the benefit.  These efforts can quickly lead to much more difficult to maintain applications.  And as you say, savvy users can still grab the data.  At some point a copyright issue is a legal problem, not a technical problem.  (I'm reminded of a client who once proudly demonstrated their multi-million-dollar effort to make medical information in their web app non-copyable.  It used all kinds of horrible hacks.  No highlight, no copy/paste, no screen shots, etc.  They weren't amused when I took out my phone and snapped a picture of the patient data.)

Comment: David. Yes, I do get your point. The objective is to make it more difficult. Same as downloading a whole site via a site downloader... It cannot be prevented by those who are determined. But trying is prevention in a way if it makes copying difficult.

Comment: To answer Honk der Hase. I'm old school. I believe data should be shared freely, but not stolen and used for someone else's gain and profit. Because we cannot rely on good manners we have to try and prevent it.

Comment: A thing to think about when your rationale becomes, "Let's just hide it from the casual user", is the *value* of the content you want to protect. If it's not very valuable, then why protect it at all? If it **is** valuable, then somebody else probably thinks it's valuable too, so protection against casual users doesn't really do you any good.

Comment: if we're getting creative, I vote for ASCII Art https://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=ANSI%20Regular&t=Lorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet

Comment: Basically, you cannot do what you're asking. Recall that the thing on the other end of the HTTP connection may not even be a browser. If you send content from your server and it can be displayed on a client screen, you've already lost the battle. If you want to protect content, create an authentication and authorization scheme so that people have to log in and accept a T&C statement to view the content.

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags. The given post has no connection to PHP, jQuery, or AJAX

Answer (score 1):

You could use canvas for the text, that way it won't appear on devtools.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var text = "72 101 108 108 111 32 87 111 114 108 100".split(" ").map(item => String.fromCharCode(item)).join("");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText(text, 10, 50);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Using server side (Node or PHP ) you can generate the element or a PNG of that text. Text flow would be a problem but take comfort it's the same with PDF generation. You could be using images or canvases with equal width, then line wrapping wouldn't be so horrible.

Comment: It's still visible in the Source tab of DevTools, although you can obfuscate that.

Comment: I will try the canvas approach as suggested.  And Barmar, your comment is interesting but I would not know how.  Could you explain a little?

Comment: Like from the source of the page. Anyway, I added "obfuscation" for the text as to hide it from casual user which does view-source.

Comment: Also note that the text content will be visible in the Network developer tab if it's fetched via xhr or `fetch()`, or if it's in the page content then it's still totally visible.